# onCreate() not being called on orientation change

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, oncreate, android-orientation

I have an `MainActivty` which consists of a **Navigation Drawer**. The navigation drawer code is pretty close to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Now the `MainActivty` loads `FragmentA` upon start. The Navigation Drawer is supposed to be only available from `FragmentA`. So far so good, all works fine.

Now I tap something on the screen, which the `MainActivity` recognizes, and replaces `FragmentA` by `FragmentB`. When I am on `FragmentB`, in the `FragmentB.onCreate()` I call the following:

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
((MainActivity)getActivity()).mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); //ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle is a public class variable in MainActivity
```

This is in order to replace the **Drawer carat** in the actionbar with a **Back arrow**. This works fine as well.

Now, at this point, if I change the screen orientation the `MainActivty.onCreate()` is not called. The `FragmentB.onCreate()` is still called, and the `mDrawerToggle` is null as the `MainActivity.onCreate()` was not called. So the app crashes due to a  `NullPointerException`.

I am NOT using: `android:configChanges="orientation"` for the activity. I am not sure how to fix this, as the example code in Android documentation has only a single Activity and no other fragments. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** When you want your `Fragment` to change the `ActionBar`, simply call `fragmentToSwitchTo.setHasOptionsMenu(true)` before you commit your `FragmentTransaction` and then call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will then work inside the `Fragment` just like an `Activity`.

Comment: Hi, not sure how overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` will help. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm not saying it'll help your current problem, I wouldn't posted an answer if that was the case. But it seems that you think one has to call `((MainActivity) getAcitivty())` to edit the `ActionBar`. Once you have many fragments this can be cleaned up by doing the above method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a silly mistake. The Fragments `onCreate()` is called before the Activity's `onCreate()`. So I just put the code referring to the Activity in the `Fragment.onCreateView()`. Now all is well :)